# How to configure CkEditor's styles dropdown?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I have made changes to the configuration of CKEditor for the basic_html rule set as follows:

[image: CK Editor configuration]

When I then try to use the editor, however, I get the following:

[image: Editor as visible on actual page]

I have tried clearing the cache multiple times.
I have tried rebuilding the cache with drush cache-rebuild.

Is there something else you are suppose to do to be able to configure CKEditor in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1. Your Custom style should be present in your CSS file. 2. Your FILTER SETTING should be proper.** To check, same way as yours, I just enabled style and and put `h1.heading-a|Title`(which I took from css/base/elements.css for example purpose) in style dropdown and and it did show up as shown in the second image.

> [image]

Second Image

> [image]

**Hence, the issue is, to properly put the `Class|Key` in the `Styles dropdown` section and make sure that it is available in `CSS`.**

Later to check the custom one, I did put `h2.myclass {color: red}` in `elements.css` and saved and cleared cache. And as you can see it showed up in following image

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE-1: FILTER SETTING**

Now the reason why, horizontal line and underline icon are not visible as you have stated in your comment. For that you need to check the FILTER SETTINGS. Have you played with `Limit allow HTML tags and correct faulty HTML` list which you can see at the bottom of the basic HTML setting page as shown in following image. If you delete `<hr>` from the list the icon will not shown up. Just I checked, if I remove `<hr>` form list the icon also gets disappeared.

> [image]

**And your Enable filter setting should be as shown in following image.**

[image]

Comment: Replicating your process there is no change in my result. I still get no custom styles. Additionally, and I should have made this clearer in my original post, if you look at my Basic HTML settings above, I have added a number of built in items such as 'horizontal line'  and 'underline' which also do not appear when I try to use the editor.

Comment: Are you using Bartik theme?

Comment: Ok Got the Problem. Have you played with `Limit allow HTML tags and correct faulty HTML` list which you can see at the bottom of the basic HTML setting page, See image I have updated in my answer. If you delete <hr> from the list the icon will not shown up. Just I checked. If i remove <hr> icon also gets disappeared

Comment: Check `Enable Filters` setting also as shown in second updated image. It should be as shown.

Comment: I am using Seven for admin and a custom theme for the public site. Ok the <hr> and <u> tag fix did work, they were not in the allowed tags for some reason.

Comment: This is odd. I copied the site - sql dumb and full set of files and loaded it a new vagrant instance and in that instance my custom styles appear... I am not seeing any kind of of php error on my main site however no custom styles are appearing...

Comment: Ok I had to add <h2 class> to the allowed filters. Why would this be missing on one version of the site and not the other? Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Actually... no it is still behaving oddly. I tried adding a <table class='mycass'> style and it will not show up in the style menu no matter what I put in the allowed filters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43115/discussion-between-codenext-and-raf).

Comment: This has to be one of the most annoyingly badly documented issues I've dealt with Drupal; or at least in recent memory. I don't think I'm experiencing the EXACT scenario that the user in the chat described, but it might just have been an update to Ckeditor since July; the main point is the same though. Adding classes to Limit Allowed Tags: <p class=""> = ALL classes, <p class="newclass"> = Only new class, <p class="newclass othernewclass"> = Only newclass and othernewclass. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

For people on drupal 8.4: there is a bug in CKEditor itself on this manner. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2911749 for more information and patches.

> One possible workaround is to replace the ckeditor.js with that one from > Drupal 8.3.7 (should be version 4.6.2), then everything should work well > again.

In composer.json, add this to your "extra" section. See comment #33 in the link (credit to @ayalon on drupal.org):

```
"patches": {
  "drupal/core": {
    "Downgrade CkEditor until https://www.drupal.org/node/2911749 is fixed": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/fix_ckeditor_styles_dropdown-2911749-17.patch"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when using the Basic HTML text format and wanted to add a style like `p.class|Title`. The difference was that I even couldn't open the style list, because the style button was disabled.

To fix this I edited the text format and added `<p class="">` to the "Limit allowed HTML tags" field.

Comment: In my case, it was adding `<div class id>` to the allowed HTML tags field. This is a stupid bug!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you missed to **class** attribute for allowed HTML tags. Change

```
<a href hreflang> <em>
```

to

```
<a class href hreflang> <em>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it did not work, because the line with a specific CSS class under "Styles dropdown" was too long.

This works:

```
code.c-bolt-code-snippet__code.c-bolt-code-snippet__code--block|Codeblock
```

but this does not work:

```
code.c-bolt-code-snippet__code.c-bolt-code-snippet__code--block.c-bolt-code-snippet-syntax--light|Codeblock
```